# intellij configuration html formatting does not work

Tags: html, templates, intellij-idea, formatting, editor

I tried every configuration settings like CODE STYLE > FILE AND CODE TEMPLATES or HTML FORMAT SETTINGS ,but no matter what I did I can never reform this ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
</div>
<script src="src/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

what I want is as below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="src/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My code style format for HTML is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code formatting is configured in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**; to get the desired result, you need to remove `html` and `body` from **Do not indent children of:** list in **Other** tab:

[image]